# How to add animation on container changing its width realtime

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am making a form that expands when the user enters any character/key and gets back to its original width when there is no character left, for the plus point, I want to add animation to that expandable form so it gives a smooth look.

[Here is the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-10-tailwind-2-0-forked-1iw7zh?file=/components/Footer.js) and **I want this action as follows**[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Comment: i just tried this : "message.length > 0 && transform transition duration-200 scale-125  ease-in-out ". it's not the right parameters you just need to fine tune this, but as you can see the input grows smoothly. try adding a condition with an animatin when message.lenght ===0 to see the input animate back to its initial size

Answer (score 0):

Not in **React** but I made an example in **Vanilla JS** hope it helps. I used `CSS` variables for changing width and making it smooth.

Instead of removing `svg` icons completely try scaling it down to **0** or changing it opacity to **0**

```js
const btns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.btn'))
const input = document.querySelector('input')

btns.shift() // for leaving first button

input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  btns.forEach((btn) => {
    if (event.target.value.trim().length > 0) {
      btn.classList.add('scale-0')

      btn.parentElement.classList.add('width-50')
    } else {
      btn.classList.remove('scale-0')

      if (btn.parentElement.classList.contains('width-50')) {
        btn.parentElement.classList.remove('width-50')
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```css
@import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KunalTanwar/normalize/css/normalize.inter.min.css';
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.row {
  --column-gap: 1rem; /* 8px */
  
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 525px;
  column-gap: var(--column-gap);
}

.row input {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-radius: 100vmax;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
}

.container {
  --column-gap: 0.5rem; /* 16px */
  --btn-size: 3.125rem; /* 50px */
  
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: inherit;
  column-gap: var(--column-gap);
  width: calc(var(--column-gap) * 3 + var(--btn-size) * 4);
  transition: width 250ms ease;
}

.container.width-50 {
  width: var(--btn-size);
}

.container .btn {
  width: var(--btn-size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  transition: transform 250ms ease;
}

.container .btn.scale-0 {
  transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="btn">1</button>
    <button class="btn">2</button>
    <button class="btn">3</button>
    <button class="btn">4</button>
  </div>

  <input type="text" />
</div>
```